# How to add user selected value from drop down in IList object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a jQuery function which reads user selected drop down value. I want to fill up the `List` object with user selected values.

i.e. Let's say drop down has Apple and Orange. If the user selects an apple, I can read the value by `selected.val()` and text by `selected.text()` but not sure how to assign those value to `Partner` object.

In C# I can initiate the object and add a loop and assign the value but don't know how to do that on client side.

jQuery:

```
 function addPartner() {
    var container = $("#partner-container");
    var selected = $("#selectPartner :selected");
    var text = selected.text(); // want to set this as PartnerName 
    var val = selected.val(); // want to set this as PartnerId 

    alert(text); // Apple
    alert(val); // 1

    // Approach - 1
    $('#Partners').append($("", { value: val, text: text }));

    // Approach - 2
    $('#Partners').append($("", { PartnerId: val, PartnerName: text }));
  }

  <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Partners) %>
```

Error in both approaches:

```
 "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type '' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."
```

C#:

```
 [DisplayName(@"Partner Name")]
  public List<IntegrationPartner> Partners { get; set; }

  public class IntegrationPartner
  {
    public int PartnerId { get; set; }

    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
  }
```

Most example refers populating drop down from jQuery but I want to populate `List` based on drop down selection.

Comment: You'll need to send a request back to the server to do that. Are you talking about doing a GET or a POST with the selected value?

Comment: I am trying to do POST

Comment: Do you have a controller action you are posting to?